# why scrolling is disabled when i add new element in javascript dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

i have in my code a `add button` when i click on it a new `div` element is added to the layout, the problem is when i add multiple rows dynamically the scroll of the page is not working

below how i add the element on button click

```
function add(event) {

  event.preventDefault();  
      var deletebutton =  document.createElement("button");

    deletebutton.addEventListener("click",function(evt){
      deleterow(evt,'div' + i + '')
      });


 var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
 newDiv.className="form-group";
 newDiv.id="div" + i;

 newDiv.appendChild(deletebutton);
 
  document.getElementById("tab_logic").appendChild(newDiv);

  }
```

below the code of button i click to add dynamically the row

```
<button id="add_row" style="background-color:#90EE90;"  onclick="add(event)" >
                             
                          </button></div>
```

Comment: *"the scroll of the page is not working"*  in which way? What do you expect to happen and what is happening instead?

Comment: when adding 10 new rows dynamically the page must scroll to see all the div i add

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById("tab_logic")`

This is the element you probably want to look at. There's a couple of things that could be happening:

- The element you're adding is `position: absolute` so it's not part of the element layout, so the element doesn't know it needs to scroll
- `#tab_logic` has the `overflow: hidden` style set, or no `overflow` style set, perhaps it should be `overflow: auto`
- Your `#tab_logic` element's *parent* could also have these same
  problems: follow it up the tree and make sure there's not an absolute layout or an overflow setting somewhere that's causing the problem.

Comment: i notice something when i change the zoom of the webpage the scroll appears

Comment: Oh, then in that case, the `<div>`s you're adding aren't overflowing their parent yet, so no scrollbar appears. Try adding more than ten divs, maybe 100?

Comment: i tried to add 100 or more but not showing any scroll

Comment: the scroll also appears when i change the zoom of the web oage

Comment: Well, I'm afraid it's at the point where you have to research this yourself some more, and find some more clues.  Hopefully these pointers we've discussed can help out when you discover something new.  It's also usually a good idea if you're stuck to move on to a different problem, where you might learn something new that helps you come back to this problem. Good luck!